# Ошибка "non-static method format(Date)" при использовании Date и DateFormat

Tags: java, android-studio, ооп, дата, simpledateformat

Пишу код, который должен получать текущие дату и время, а потом разделять отдельные части по отдельным целочисленным переменным. Часть кода, где и возникла ошибка:

```
DateFormat day1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
Date date=new Date();
int day=Integer.parseInt(DateFormat.format(date));
```

Так вот, само сообщение об ошибке:

`non-static method format(Date) cannot be referenced from a static context day=Integer.parseInt(DateFormat.format(new Date()));`

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь в решении ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `format()` не является статическим, поэтому его нельзя вызывать статическим способом, т. н. `Имя_Класса.имя_метода()`

Не статические методы надо вызывать через ссылку, д.с.

> Единственный способ вызвать нестатический метод из статического метода - это иметь экземпляр класса, содержащего нестатический метод. По определению, нестатический метод-это метод, который принадлежит экземпляру некоторого класса, тогда как статический метод принадлежит самому классу.

Более подробно можно почитать про статические методы в [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):

> Язык программирования Java поддерживает статические методы, а также статические переменные.  Статические методы, объявления которых имеют модификатор `static`, должны вызываться с именем класса без необходимости создания экземпляра класса, как в
>
> ```
> ClassName.methodName (аргументы)
> ```
>
> Примечание. Вы также можете ссылаться на статические методы с помощью ссылки на объект, например
>
> ```
> instanceName.methodName (аргументы)
> ```
>
> но это не рекомендуется, потому что это не дает понять, что это методы класса.
>
> Обычно статические методы используются для доступа к статическим полям.  Например, мы могли бы добавить статический метод к классу `Bicycle` для доступа к статическому полю `numberOfBicycles`:
>
> ```
> public static int getNumberOfBicycles () {
>     return numberOfBicycles;
> }
> ```
>
> Не все комбинации переменных и методов экземпляра и класса разрешены:
>
> - Методы экземпляра могут напрямую обращаться к переменным экземпляра и методам экземпляра.
> - Методы экземпляра могут напрямую обращаться к переменным класса и методам класса.
> - Методы класса могут напрямую обращаться к переменным класса и методам класса.
> - Методы класса не могут напрямую обращаться к переменным экземпляра или методам экземпляра - они должны использовать ссылку на объект.  Кроме того, методы класса не могут использовать ключевое слово `this`, поскольку нет экземпляра, на который можно было бы ссылаться.

---

**Что надо поменять в коде:**

```java
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
Date date=new Date();
int day=Integer.parseInt(df.format(date));
```