# Non-static method 'sum(java.util.List<Box<? extends java.lang.Number>>)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, list, generics, static

Дали задание сделать метод типа double который на вход принимает list<Box>(Лист боксов), причем в боксе лежит любые данные которые являются наследником Number и нужно вычислить сумму всех элементов. Вроде все сделал, но не могу понять почему Java просит сделать этот метод Static. Объясните кто может. Буду благодарен если найдете какие-нибудь ошибочки)

Класс Box

```
public class Box<T> {
    T value;

    public Box(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void set(T v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public T get() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Класс Test(main)

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Box<? extends Number>> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(new Box<>(0.1));
        list.add(new Box<>(3.228322));
        list.add(new Box<>(123));
        list.add(new Box<>(12.123));
        list.add(new Box<>(1135.14144));
        list.add(new Box<>(2341234.1234234));
        list.add(new Box<>(112322));
        list.add(new Box<>(124));
        list.add(new Box<>(632));
        list.add(new Box<>(474));
        list.add(new Box<>(245));
        list.add(new Box<>(235));
        list.add(new Box<>(2345));
        System.out.println(BlockSum.sum(list));
    }
}
```

Класс BlockSum в котором находиться метод суммы

```
import java.util.List;

public class BlockSum {

    double sum(List<Box<? extends Number>> list) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (Box<? extends Number> T1 : list) {
            double asd = T1.get().doubleValue();
            sum += asd;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не создаете экземпляр класса BlockSum, Поэтому он и просит сделать метод статическим. Либо надо сначала создать экземпляр (`BlockSum bs = new BlockSum();`) и потом уже использовать `System.out.println(bs.sum(list));`, либо делать метод статическим

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка "non-static method format(Date)" при использовании Date и DateFormat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1268930/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-non-static-method-formatdate-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-date-%d0%b8-dateformat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш метод sum() не является статическим, т.е. **относится к экземпляру** класса BlockSum.
Соответственно, для его использования необходимо создать экземпляр.

Если же Вы хотите, чтобы метод **относился к классу**, то его необходимо пометить ключевым словом *static*.

```
double static sum(List<Box<? extends Number>> list) { ... }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, понял!

Comment: @ДмитрийАгеев, всегда пожалуйста. Если ответ помог - примите его. Галочка в левой части ответа.