# Наследование статических полей java

Tags: java, наследование

Есть класс

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
  static String name = "Not initialized";

  public static void load(String Name) {
    name = Name;
  }
  public static String getName() {
    return name;
  }
   ...
}
```

И его наследники

```
public abstract class First extends SuperClass{}
public abstract class Second extends SuperClass{}
```

При выполнении `First.load("first");` в `First.getName()` получим "first", но если после выполнить `Second.load("second");`, то в в `First.getName()` получим уже "second".
Т.е. статические поля для наследников общие. Есть ли возможность их как-то разделить?  Поскольку поле name используется и в суперклассе и в наследниках, то я не могу просто объявить его только в наследниках или в двух местах одновременно, так как функция load изменит только поле суперкласса.

Comment: Зачем в абстрактном классе статик? Убери статик и все встанет на свои места.

Comment: А как тогда вызывать методы? First.load() в таком случае Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: используйте экземаляры.

Comment: И каждый раз при вызове мне нужно будет создавать экземпляр, что мне не совсем подходит

Comment: так вы задачу не описали свою, потому только вы знаете, что вам подходит )

Comment: В общем решил делать экземпляры, которые будут в статических полях другого класса, по другому решить не удалось. По факту получается тот-же статик, но в обёртке

Comment: Можно сделать статические поля нестатическими и в функцию `load()` передавать ссылку на объект. См. также [почему нельзя нестатические методы вызывать из статического контекста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1268943/204920).